# User cannot access own document in _users in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I am having problems with CouchDB 3.1.0 on Windows. I have installed it, during the installation created a admin user (`admin:admin`) and then created a user as the documentation states:

```
$ curl -X PUT http://admin:admin@localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:jan \
>      -H "Accept: application/json" \
>      -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
>      -d '{"name": "jan", "password": "apple", "roles": [], "type": "user"}'
{"ok":true,"id":"org.couchdb.user:jan","rev":"1-fd5a90118f51fb895d594f2fdfa9b12f"}
```

Fine. Now let me get the user doc:

```
$ curl -X GET http://jan:apple@localhost:5984/_users/org.couchdb.user:jan
{"error":"forbidden","reason":"You are not allowed to access this db."}
```

What am I doing wrong? What did I miss?

It did work in CouchDB 2.3, surely.

Thanks.

Comment: Databases in 3.X are now admin only by default. See https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/whatsnew/3.0.html for more details. I guess you'll need to allow users to access your `_users`  db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for CouchDB 3.x is unfortunately out of date. As of today, the [Authentication Database](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/intro/security.html#authentication-database) section in the security documentation states:

> Users may only access (`GET /_users/org.couchdb.user:Jan`) or modify
> (`PUT /_users/org.couchdb.user:Jan`) documents that they own

However, it does not state that users by default do not have access to *any* documents in the `_users` database.

In order to allow access, one must first change the `users_db_security_editable` flag to true in the settings, and then clear the `members -> roles` list in the `_users` security object. This list has `_admin` in it by default. Alternatively, you could add a role to your users and add that role to the `members -> roles` instead.

Note that this will allow users read *and* write access to their user document.

There is an [open Github issue](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-documentation/issues/513) to amend the documentation.

Other sources:

https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/2881

https://github.com/apache/couchdb/issues/2730